# Get list of specific members using MailChimp API v3.0

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

In previous version of MailChimp API there was option to get specific list of members. You was able to send list of emails and get those members.

In version 3.0 there is only option to get ALL members or to get ONE specific members:

1. `/lists/{list_id}/members` => get all Members
2. `/lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}` => get ONE member by Email

So both option is not good. What If I have 100 emails and I want to get that 100 members from my Mailchimp List which have 20k subscribers.

With first option I would need to get all 20k members from the list and then take the 100 which I need? That's bad.

With second option I would need to loop 100 emails and send 100 request to get each member.

Is there any workaround to get list of members querying by multiple emails in v3.0?

Answer (score 0):

In API I can't find filter/query like this neither.

I would make a request to get all the 20k members, and with a simply linq/foreach/filter. With this You will get your 100 members in JSON so I think thats the fastest, and easiest way to do it.

You can use batch operations, but that's almost the same like you loop requests, and harder to get the results and much slower ( need to check the batch is ready what can take several minutes, and wait for it, than get the result url, what will give you a .tar.gz so need to unzip twice, etc) So I think this is a dead idea for "GET" requests.